# Replacing an object of the UserLoginForm class with one of my own class

Tags: forms, 8

Is it possible to replace an object of the [UserLoginForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Form%21UserLoginForm.php/class/UserLoginForm/8.2.x) class with one of my own class?

What I want to do is replacing the login form with a custom one which would ask users to enter a code sent to their email address, once they entered the correct user credentials.

The problem is that an object of that class is created from [UserController::userPage()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Controller%21UserController.php/function/UserController%3A%3AuserPage/8.2.x).

```
if ($user->id()) {
  $response = new RedirectResponse(url('user/' . $user->id(), array('absolute' => TRUE)));
}
else {
  $response = drupal_get_form(UserLoginForm::create($this->container), $request);
}
```

I know I can implement [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8) to alter the form, but I would like to use a class like `UserLogin`, and replacing `$form_state['build_info']['callback_object']` with the object of my class in `hook_form_alter()` is probably too late.

Is it possible to use a class for altering the user login form? How?

Comment: That is an extremely good question, because there is no real solution. Please please file a bug pointing out your problem. This is not a common pattern in core, but it needs to be fixed ASAP and not used elsewhere.

Comment: Please see https://drupal.org/node/2073165, once that issue is resolved I will write an answer with the correct way to override a form that is not directly accessed from a route. Until that issue is resolved, the answer is still "too bad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the question, the problem was that `UserController::userPage()` expressly created an object of the class `UserLoginForm`. The method has been changed, and now it contains the following code, which doesn't contain any explicit reference to that class.

```
public function userPage() {
  return $this->redirect('entity.user.canonical', array('user' => $this->currentUser()->id()));
}
```

Using a route subscriber that extends [`RouteSubscriberBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21RouteSubscriberBase.php/class/RouteSubscriberBase/8.2.x) is possible to change the form associated with a route.

```
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class MymoduleRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('user.login')) {
      $route->setDefault('_form', '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyModuleLoginForm');
    }
  }
}
```